# Reading input from Python and print out in while loop

Tags: python, c++, input, while-loop

I wonder how I can translate the following C++ code to Python code.

```
int n;
while (cin >> n)
cout << n <<endl;
```

My guess is it would be something like this

```
import sys

while n = raw_input():
   print n + "\n"
```

but it doesn't work... Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like this:

```
import sys # why?

n = "string"

while n:
    n = raw_input()
    print n + '\n'
```

However

```
while n = raw_input(): # incorrect.
```

This won't work because:

1. `n` is not defined
2. In any case, to test equality you should generally use `==`, though not in this particular case, as it would mean basically, while `n` is equal to `empty string( '' )`

example:

```
>>> raw_input() == ''
True
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `n = raw_input()` in Python does not return a value whereas `cin >> n` in C++ does. (This saves the programmers from the most common error of replacing `==` with `=`)

You can try something like.

```
n = raw_input("Enter Something: ")
while n:
    print n
    n = raw_input("Enter Something: ")
```

Test Run :

```
>>> 
Enter Something: Monty
Monty
Enter Something: Python
Python
Enter Something: Empty Line Next
Empty Line Next
Enter Something:
```

**P.S**- There's no need of the `import sys` in this case (if you're not using it anywhere else in your code). Also, `print` statement automatically moves the cursor to the next line, so you need not add `\n` in this case.

Comment: Thank you. I tested it on this website http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php and I got this error report:Enter Something: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in 
    n = raw_input("Enter Something: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: This has something to do with the online interpreter most probably. Why not use the IDLE provided by the Python package? Or use Python in shell.

Comment: I see. What is Python in shell? Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you have Linux, then your distro might have Python pre-installed. Just open up the terminal and type Python. If you're on Windows, search for Python Windows setup on Google and install Python and launch the IDLE shell.

Comment: Thank you, Sukrit Kalra. Yes I'm using linux. I typed python on the terminal and it's installed. For C++, I write my code in gEdit (a text editor) and compile my code using the g++ compiler in Linux. What should I do for python? What compiler should I use? I don't think g++ compiler works for python...